# Collect Signature Workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: designer-workflow

I am trying to create a Collect signature workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 using the -SharePoint 2010/2013 workflow.

I am unable to find the Collect Signature workflow in the "Action" list.

Any help would be appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Have you activated the `Workflows` site collection feature?

Comment: yes its activated and also listed in workflow section in SharePoint designer as Collect Signatures - SharePoint 2010

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following. Could you provide e.g. a screenshot in your original question?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding there is no possibility to create custom Collect Signature Workflow using Sharepoint designer

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a signature column, something like an [Infowise Signature](https://www.infowisesolutions.com/product/SignatureField) would do it, there are other companies that have a similar offering too.

The 'signature' can be username + password or if you have a 'signature pad' then you could save actual hand written signatures.